# Manage site to specific folder without server side and editing links

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a project which should be located in certain folder on server (site.com/folder/), and locally on site.com. I'm using Webpack, React, and React Router.
When I upload all of the files to specific folder on server, it cannot resolve the paths to js files, images, and all of the routes mentioned without that folder.

Is there any way to manage paths within configs without server access?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should create a PUBLIC folder (example: /public) on server side and the structure /public folder is looked like a router.

Comment: opinions and answers are both different. Please feel free to add a comment when you have enough reputation.

Comment: @RatanUdayKumar I think my opinion can help him, I'm so sorry if my solution is wrong or not a best choise

Comment: if you are confident in your solution.  don't post like opinion.